# Generic Interface Dependency injection in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, interface

I have the below Generic Class & Interface implementations

```
public interface IHttpClient<T> where T : class
{
   public Task<List<T>> GetJsonAsync(string url);
}


public class HttpClient<T> : IHttpClient<T> where T:class
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public HttpClient(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

  

    public async Task<List<T>> GetJsonAsync(string url)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,url);
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(result);
        }

        return null;
    }
     
}
```

and this is how I try to register them in the startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {      
     services.AddScoped(typeof(IHttpClient<>), typeof(HttpClient<>));
 }
```

My Controller:

```
  private readonly IHttpClient<Feed> _feedClient;
  public HomeController( IHttpClient<Feed> _client)
    {
       
        _feedClient = _client;

      
    }
```

and this is the error I'm getting

**InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory' while attempting to activate...**

what is it that I'm missing? any help is very appreciated..

Comment: Seems you did not register your `IHttpClientFactory` in IoC

Comment: Also add `services.AddHttpClient();`

Comment: Thank you Knoop, it worked smoothly after adding the code =))

Answer (score 1):

You should register `HttpClient` in startup class like this

```cs
//register
services.AddHttpClient();
```

use

```cs
public YourController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{ 
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
}
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
```

**Another options**

```cs
//register
services.AddHttpClient("YourClientName", c =>
{
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://yoururl");
});
```

use

```cs
public YourController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{ 
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
}
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("YourClientName");
```